Padé approximant of \$\exp(x)\$
In mathematics, a Padé approximant (Wikipedia, MathWorld) is the "best" approximation of a function by a rational function. For a function \$f(x)\$, the Padé approximant of order \$[m/n]\$ is a rational function of the form
$$R(x) = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^m a_k x^k}{\sum_{k=0}^n b_k x^k}$$
such that \$R(x)\$ agrees with \$f(x)\$ up to order \$m+n\$ at \$x=0\$, i.e.
$$\begin{align*}
f(0) &= R(0) \\
f'(0) &= R'(0) \\
&\vdots \\
f^{(m+n)}(0) &= R^{(m+n)}(0)
\end{align*}$$
When it exists, the Padé approximant (as a rational function) is unique. Sometimes we also require that \$b_0 = 1\$, so that the coefficients \$a_k\$ and \$b_k\$ are also uniquely determined. But in this challenge, we will not require this.
Task
In this challenge, you need to find the Padé approximant of the exponential function \$\exp(x)\$ of order \$[n/n]\$, where \$n\$ is a nonnegative integer. Here are the first few results:
$$\begin{align*}
[n=0]: &\quad \frac{1}{1} \\
[n=1]: &\quad \frac{2+x}{2-x} \\
[n=2]: &\quad \frac{12+6x+x^2}{12-6x+x^2} \\
[n=3]: &\quad \frac{120+60x+12x^2+x^3}{120-60x+12x^2-x^3} \\
[n=4]: &\quad \frac{1680+840x+180x^2+20x^3+x^4}{1680-840x+180x^2-20x^3+x^4}
\end{align*}$$
You can see that the numerator and denominator are basically the same, only with alternating signs. This is only true for the Padé approximant of \$\exp(x)\$, not for other functions. So you can choose to only output the numerator, or the denominator, or the whole rational function.
As with standard sequence challenges, you may choose to:

Take an integer \$n\$ as input and output the \$n\$th term of the sequence.
Take an integer \$n\$ as input and output the first \$n\$ terms of the sequence.
Take no input and output the sequence indefinitely.

You may also use \$1\$-based indexing, i.e. taking \$n\$ and outputting the Padé approximant of order \$[n-1/n-1]\$.
You may output in any reasonable format, e.g. a list of coefficients (numerator and/or denominator), in either ascending or descending order. When you only output the numerator or the denominator, you can scale the coefficients by any nonzero factor, but the factor must be the same for the same \$n\$. The coefficients do not need to be integers.
Just like other challenges with both sequence and polynomials tags, you can also take two inputs \$n\$ and \$k\$ and output the \$k\$th coefficient (of either the numerator or the denominator) of the \$n\$th Padé approximant.
This is code-golf, so the shortest code in bytes wins.
Test cases
Here I output the coefficients of the numerators in ascending order.
0 -> [1]
1 -> [2, 1]
2 -> [12, 6, 1]
3 -> [120, 60, 12, 1]
4 -> [1680, 840, 180, 20, 1]
5 -> [30240, 15120, 3360, 420, 30, 1]
6 -> [665280, 332640, 75600, 10080, 840, 42, 1]
7 -> [17297280, 8648640, 1995840, 277200, 25200, 1512, 56, 1]


This is A119274.

APL(Dyalog Unicode), 12 9 bytes SBCS
It takes n and k as its left and right arguments, respectively, then outputs the coefficient of \$x^k\$ in the \$n\$-th approximant.
It calculates \$\frac{n!}{k!}\cdot{2n-k\choose n-k} = \frac{n!}{k!}\cdot\frac{(2n-k)!}{n!(n-k)!} = \frac{(2n-k)!}{k!(n-k)!}\$.
÷⍥!×-!⊣+-

÷⍥!        ⍝ n!÷k!
   ×       ⍝      times
    -      ⍝           n-k
     !     ⍝              choose from
      ⊣+-  ⍝                         n+n-k

Try it on APLgolf!
Try it on APLgolf! 12 bytes

Ruby, 41 bytes
->n,k{eval [[1,*k...n+n-=k]*?*,*1..n]*?/}

Try it online!
Same formula as @Tbw, but 1-based to make it shorter.

05AB1E, 9 bytes
xs0)α!.»÷

Inputs in the order \$n,k\$.
Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
x          # Double the first (implicit) input (without popping)
           #  STACK: n,2n
 s         # Swap the two values
           #  STACK: 2n,n
  0        # Push 0
           #  STACK: 2n,n,0
   )       # Wrap all values on the stack into a list
           #  STACK: [2n,n,0]
    α      # Get the absolute difference with the second (implicit) input
           #  STACK: [abs(k-2n),abs(k-n),abs(k-0)], aka [2n-k,n-k,k]
     !     # Get the factorial of each
           #  STACK: [(2n-k)!,(n-k)!,k!]
      .»   # Left-reduce this list by:
        ÷  #  Integer-dividing
           #   STACK: (2n-k)!/(n-k)!/k!
           # (which is output implicitly as result)  


J, 9 bytes
%&!*-![+-

Computes the same thing as everyone else. n as left arg, k as right arg.
%&!*-![+-
        -   NB. n-k
      [     NB. n
       +    NB. addition
    -       NB. n-k
     !      NB. combinations, x!y -> C(y,x)
%&!         NB. take factorial of n and k and divide the results
   *        NB. multiplication

More simply put
%&!*-![+-
    -![+-   NB. (n-k)!(n+n-k)
%&!         NB. (n!)%(k!)
   *        NB. multiply the results

Attempt This Online!

JavaScript (ES6), 44 bytes
Expects (n)(k) and returns the corresponding coefficient.
n=>k=>(g=n=>n?n*g(n-1):1)(2*n-k)/g(k)/g(n-k)

Try it online!

Vyxal, 9 8 bytes
2ʀ*Ṙε¡ƒ/

Try it Online!
Getting the inputs to work nicely was annoying, and it's likely that there's a byte to be shaved here (I wish vysearch was a thing). Same formula as everyone else. -1 inspired by Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer.
2ʀ       # [0, 1, 2]
  *Ṙ     # [2n, n, 0]
    ε    # [2n-k, n-k, k]
     ¡   # Factorial of each
      ƒ/ # (2n-k)! / (n-k)! / k!


Charcoal, 18 bytes
ＮθＮηＩ÷Π⁻⊕…θ⊗θηΠ⊕…η

Attempt This Online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Uses the same formula from @Tbw's answer.
Ｎθ                  Input `n` as a number
  Ｎη                Input `k` as a number
         …          Range from
          θ         Input `n` to
            θ       Input `n`
           ⊗        Doubled
        ⊕           Vectorised incremented
       ⁻            Vectorised subtract
             η      Input `k`
      Π             Take the product, i.e. `(2n-k)!/(n-k)!`
     ÷              (Integer) divided by
                 η  Input `k`
                …   Range from `0`
               ⊕    Vectorised incremented
              Π     Take the product, i.e. `k!`
    Ｉ               Cast to string
                    Implicitly print


Uiua 0.13.0-dev.2, 15 bytes SBCS
÷∩/×+1⊃⇡-:+1+⇡.

Try on Uiua Pad!
Takes \$n\$ and \$k\$ and outputs the coefficient of \$x^k\$ in the numerator of the \$n\$th approximant. This is \$\frac{(2n-k)!}{k!(n-k)!}\$.
